# why does google scholar find a paper I wrote for a course?

Tags: google-scholar

I just found a [citation] result on google scholar listing a paper I wrote for a seminar as an undergrad. The result isn't a link, it just lists the title, author and year. This can't have been cited anywhere because I only turned it in for a grade and my professor didn't do anything with it afterwards.

Did scholar pull the data out of my email and count email discussions as "citations?" I might have mentioned the paper by email to two people besides the professor.

EDIT - this is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Was there a plagiarism check?

Comment: it's possible but I'd be *very* surprised. I submitted it as PDF and I worked fairly closely with the faculty person before handing it in. I don't think he would have taken the time to upload it anywhere.

Comment: Isn't there usually a "Cited by" link for those results?

Comment: Did you try googling for the paper to see where it might be mentioned online?

Comment: @Maeher, only when the hit is a link with more information. EDIT: actually I just found one that isn't a link but also has "cited by." The result I'm talking about just has the star icon, the quotation mark icon, and the related articles link

Comment: @Kimball, I just did and I couldn't find anything

Comment: @Maeher The absence of a "Cited by" link in a Google Scholar record usually indicates that it has zero citations, which would render this particular Citation record inconsistent.

Comment: Is or was it hosted, or at least listed (i.e. just your name and its title) somewhere on your university's website? We've had a lot of fun in the past with unrergrad seminar papers (i.e. documents that often do not contain any research, let alone anything novel, and just *look like* papers in terms of structure and formatting) that Google Scholar decided to count as PhD dissertations by seemingly following an "everything mentioned on an academic website must be a scientific publication" approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report for Google Scholar, and academia.SE is not Google's support forum.